# I want to set up a few different Scrollviews on a few different ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am having trouble adding scrollview to a few different View Controllers - so far I have then on the front end side of the view controller but, I havent been able to figure out how to make them work (I am a beginner)

Here is the code

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

     @IBOutlet weak var firstscrollView: UIScrollView!
     @IBOutlet weak var firstimageview: UIImageView!
     @IBOutlet weak var secondscrollView: UIScrollView!
     @IBOutlet weak var secondimageView: UIImageView!

     override func viewDidLoad() {

         super.viewDidLoad()

         self.firstscrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
         self.firstscrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

         self.secondscrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
         self.secondscrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0
     }

     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
         super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
         // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
     }

     func viewForZooming(in firstscrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

         return self.firstimageview
         return self.secondimageView
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First assign `delegate` for both `UIScrollView` by `firstscrollView.delegate = self` and `secondscrollView.delegate = self` in `viewDidLoad`.

Then in delegate method check for `UIScrollView` like this

```
func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

    if scrollView == firstscrollView {
        return firstimageview
    } else if scrollView == secondscrollView {
        return secondscrollView
    }
    return nil
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: I got an error in the AppDelegate file on this line:                             class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {                                        saying: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: Make sure your outlets are connected and delegates are assigned properly. Is there any way I can look for a project or file if you still have issues?

Comment: I keep getting this error message
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value  and it goes to this line          self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0

Comment: Is your outlets are connected properly?

Comment: Yeah, when I run the app it says build succeeded then it crash and say this line "self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0"

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
     
        
        self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

          }
    

    
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        
        if scrollView == scrollView {
            return imageView
        }
        return nil
        }
    
}

Comment: I meant the actual project? I won't be able to figure out without actual files. There must be something wrong. It should be `scrollView` which is nil.